# filter_var versus preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Morning all

I'm converting a site that I'm working on to be compliant with the latest version of PHP, so I'm going through and replacing all instances of ereg with their non-depreciated equivalent. However I was told about a handy built-in function with PHP called filter_var.

What my question is, is would it make sense to go with filter_var over preg_match? As in is there a performance boost or any other benefits to choosing one over the other, and if so what are they?

Comment: Can you please provide an example code which you'll refactoring? As far as I can see `filter_var` is not about regular expressions.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev He is speaking about the validation filter, `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` for the PHP filter functions. https://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[filter_var](https://www.php.net/filter_var) — Filters a variable with a specified filter 
[preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match) — Perform a regular expression match

I guess use could use filter_var to filter variables but as a replacement for preg_match I don't think is a good idea for upgrading from ereg as filter_var doesn't use regex and you would have to rewrite a lot of the functionality/logic to do this.

Comment: I stand corrected, as I thought it did for the various items it used.

Comment: Just a clarification: PHP's **`filter_var()` function does use a regex internally to perform the validation**. See the PHP source code to verify this: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L529

Comment: @AmalMurali You mean you can chose to use the `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` filter with `filter_var()`, but `filter_var()`, as far as I know, has no default, internal, regular expression functionality. It may be true that the code behind `filter_var()` uses regular expressions to validate the lengths of strings (etc...). Using `filter_var()` most likely is a highly indirect way to use regular expressions. I believe a motivation behind these functions was an attempt to establish consistency (in an abstract way), as filtering is a common task performed in many applications.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge: The OP was asking if there's a performance boost for one over the other, and I was just clarifying that both use the same underlying technique to perform the task (i.e. regular expressions), so there wouldn't be much of a difference to speak of. The only difference is that one does it at a more crude level (PHP's implementation) - it may be a little faster.

Answer (score 4):

**First** of all, the PHP Manual page on filtering: https://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

**Second**, context is key. Generally speaking, filter functions are designed to use *external input* (scalars or arrays), or *internal input*. External input comes from sources like an an HTTP request / PHP engine, or a form submission.

Filter functions with the `filter_input` prefix allow you to *bypass* $_SERVER, $_COOKIE, $_POST, and $_GET superglobals entirely. Although you generally specify "where" you want the data from, filter functions *do not explicitly utilize* $_POST, $_GET, $_COOKIE, and $_SERVER. Changes you make to the variable/array elements *will not show up* in $_GET, $_POST, or $_SERVER, so using filter this way is a paradigm shift and may change the flow of your application significantly. In other words, you have to track the external input yourself. I do this for initial sanitizing (stripping, replacing, altering, etc...) of external input. I no longer use $_POST, $_GET, or $_SERVER at all. Although, I do still use $_FILES.

Functions prefixed with `filter_var` are for filtering any general array that already exists within your program. I use this after having used `filter_input`. There are many filters you can use in both cases, but your question is about **performance**.

If you chose to use the `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` filter with any of the filtering functions, I cannot imagine this indirect approach being more efficient than directly using `preg_match()`. As far as the other filters go, if they are simply 'n' number of methods/functions removed from a regular expression call, *I cannot see an improvement in efficiency there either*.

I see the filter functions as something that were designed to help improve consistency for filtering tasks that happen across many applications. They are probably not designed to be more **efficient**, but they are definitely designed to be more **accessible** than regular expressions (though I am very good with regular expressions). I prefer having direct knowledge of what's happening, but some people don't or could care less. However, the filter functions open the door to filtering strings to those who don't understand regular expressions and other basic web application security processes.

*One can certainly live without using the filter functions, though.*

What's more, I use the filter functions in conjunction with my own sanitizer and validator classes. So, I'm not asking PHP to think for me, I'm just using it to augment what I already know how to do (just in case their functions get something I miss). Defense in depth.

In summary, your best bet is simply to use `preg_match()`, unless you intend on *changing the flow* (`filter_input` functions) of input into your application. Even then, there won't be a performance boost, but you can bypass $_SERVER, $_POST, and $_GET. Also, you can take advantage of simpler, structured, consistent, filtering functionality with the ability to use a callback function (`FILTER_CALLBACK`) to call custom, in house, methods/functions (which I do as well). Also, you can still use your own regular expressions with the filter functions using the `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` filter, but again, I see no reason to believe that the performance of your application will improve if you do. Maintainability? Maybe. It depends on the person writing the code.

Answer (score 2):

Switching over to use `filter_var()` would be a great idea actually. You wouldn't be able to use your existing regular expressions, however you WOULD be able to eliminate them entirely. Often, the regex we use in our apps are simply used for simple [validation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)s and filtering, which is exactly what the `filter_var()` function is intended for.

For example, in your code, you may already have:

```
if (eregi('\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b', $_POST['email'])) {
    echo "valid";
}
```

This could be replaced by the prettier version (not relying on custom regular expressions):

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "valid";
}
```

The `filter_var()` function also has the ability to [sanitize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) out characters which aren't needed by the particular data you're examining, and would return the cleaned string (instead of a boolean):

```
$clean = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

This kind of usage with `filter_var()` would replace `ereg_replace()` type functions.

However, for the simplest of upgrades, you can just "prefix" the ereg*() family of functions with a 'p', which makes them PCRE compliant (and therefore no longer deprecated in PHP 5.3+).