# Filter_var's performance

Tags: php, regex, filter

I read that `filter_var` is not using regexp internally. Does this mean that it is much faster than `preg_match` ?

I want to check for email validation with speed performance in mind.

**Edit**

This is not a duplicate : I am not asking the difference (as for what are the advantages of filter_var and preg_match), but which is faster to execute (with or without caching). Besides, in the comments, it showed that filter_var uses regexp just like preg_match and this information was totally ignored in the related question.

Comment: Have you tried running any comparisons between the two?

Comment: @AlexandruG.: Not a duplicate since the other question is about the difference. It doesn't talk about speed, at all.

Comment: On which aspect is this a duplicate ? Is it because it contains the word filter_var and preg_match ?

Comment: @AmalMurali Per deduction the difference is the answer to this question. If filter_var is not using regexp internally, it means is faster. "How much faster" is a question which the op should first post some tests made by himself.

Comment: @AlexandruG.: Not really. `filter_var()` *does* use a regex interally. See the source code: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L529

Comment: Then obviously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544214/filter-var-versus-preg-match accepted answer is not really right...

Comment: @BabyAzerty: I've added a comment below the answer :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Missed that. Actually I think this is the second time when I look inside PHP internals. First time I was curious what `y2k_compliance` is doing internally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a quick benchmark, it seems `filter_var()` functions are *slightly* faster:

```
$times = 10000;

$result = array();

// preg_match version
// regex from https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L525
$regexp = "/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD";

$email = 'foo@bar.com';

$start_m = microtime();
$start = time();
for ($i=0; $i < $times; $i++){
      preg_match($regexp, $email);
}   

$end_m = microtime();
$end = time();
$bench = ($end - $start) + ($end_m - $start_m);
$result["preg_match"] = $bench;


// filter_var version
$start_m = microtime();
$start = time();
for ($i=0; $i < $times; $i++){
      filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

$end_m = microtime();
$end = time();
$bench = ($end - $start) + ($end_m - $start_m);
$result["filter_var"] = $bench;

print_r(
    array(
      "times" => $times,
      "results" => $result
    )
);
```

<sub>(code slightly modified version of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/uu59/2375573))</sub>

Result on my system:

```
PHP 5.5.9-1+sury.org~saucy+1 (cli) (built: Feb 13 2014 16:01:20) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

Array
(
    [times] => 10000
    [results] => Array
        (
            [preg_match] => 0.16649
            [filter_var] => 0.110912
        )

)
```

Comment: Does Zend OPCache play a role on filter_var and/or preg_match's performance ? (I upvoted your answer)

Comment: Zend OpCache optimisations would probably affect both methods; and would be unlikely to favour one over the other; but without checking the actual tokenised code you'd not be able to confirm one way or the other

Comment: This is strange, according to the question's comments, filter_var uses a regexp similar to @Amal Murali. Yet it performs better slightly !

Comment: you know why it is incorrect. It is no use to repeat.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Why do you think it's "repeating"? Can you show me one single question that actually answers the OP's question? If so, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: That does **not** answer the original question that was asked. "*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*" is a valid point and I agree with it. However, the OP's original question is different though, and I personally don't feel "*It doesn't matter.*" is a valid answer there ;)